# How to check some or one element did mount in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I need to know when Hidden Element did mount.**
I use ref to check it did mount and control this element.
And use componentDidUpdate to check when Hidden Element did mount.

But use componentDidUpdate in a big project, some elements often trigger componentDidUpdate.
I'm afraid the efficiency will be bad.
Is there another way for me to know when Hidden Element did mount?
Appreciate your help.

---

In addition, why I need to know it because I need to use a Radium package to build the animation.
When the 'someState' is true, I will auto play the animation for the element.

I use the style `animation-play-state :  'running'`.
This animation will break in the safari, but it is okay that users visit it for the first time.
When the users refresh safari and have a cache, the users visit it again causing the animation can't autoplay.

So I set `animation-play-state : paused`.
When I confirm the element did mount, I will use ref change animation-play-state to running.

I find an issue with this problem.
Link: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/912

---

My sudo code.

```js
import React from "react";

const initialState = {
  someState: false
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.hiddenElement = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");
    if (this.hiddenElement !== null) console.log("hiddenElement did Mount");
    // I will change the properties of this.hiddenElement, or others in the next steps.
  }

  render() {
    const { someState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ someState: true })}>
          Click Me
        </button>
        {someState && (
          <div ref={r => (this.hiddenElement = r)}>Hidden Element</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You could move the hidden element into its own component and use `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

Comment: "I need to know when Hidden Element did mount." Okay - why do you need to know this? What are you doing in the end? What properties would you change on the element?

Comment: @AKX 
After I revised the article, there are explanations of why I should know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so if you're using an external package and need to manipulate the element based on a state change, then you'll have to basically use `componentDidUpdate()`.
Only worry about the performance when it becomes a bottleneck (after profiling things, etc.).

Since setting a ref doesn't cause `componentDidUpdate` (it's not a bit of state), you may wish to refactor the animation-mutating method to something like this (note how the `update...()` method is called in the ref callback).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { someState: false };
    this.hiddenElement = null;
  }

  updateElementAnimation() {
    if (!this.hiddenElement) return; // not mounted yet
    if (this.state.someState) {
      this.hiddenElement.something();
    } else {
      this.hiddenElement.somethingElse();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateElementAnimation();
  }

  render() {
    const { someState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ someState: true })}>Click Me</button>
        {someState && (
          <div
            ref={r => {
              this.hiddenElement = r;
              this.updateElementAnimation();
            }}
          >
            Hidden Element
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great way. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can check inside your `componentDidUpdate` the value of your `someState`. If this is **true**, then you are sure that the element you need is rendered, as `componentDidUpdate` is invoked [**after** an update occurs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) (thus after the render method).

```js
...

 componentDidUpdate() {
   if (this.state.someState) {
     // your element is rendered, do what you need
   }
  }

...
```